# How do I accurately target my user's current geolocation on desktop browsers?

Tags: geolocation

The Geolocation API with its `getCurrentPosition` method works only using WIFI router information and IP addresses. In India where I am, there seems be NO correspondence between IP address and location.

Sometimes it shows I am in Pune - sometimes in Hyderabad - but I am in Mumbai. But When I use the same gMaps application with my mobile devices, it manages to accurately triangulate my position, which is fantastic.

But with the car pooling application I am building I need users to register and inputs their current location automatically using their laptops and desktop computers. How do I do this?

FYI: I am using chrome on Mac OSx

Answer (score 4):

There are essentially four levels of accuracy for geolocation:

- GPS, for devices with a GPS receiver
- GSM, for mobile devices connected to the mobile phone network
- WiFi, for devices within hearing distance of WiFi networks - NB the accuracy is only good if the area has been surveyed, either by the Google streetview vehicles, or by consumers crowdsourcing the information from devices with a real GPS receiver.
- IP address - ISPs get allocated a number of blocks, and typically they assign these regionally. In parts of the world where IP ranges are scarce (i.e. not in North America), you can see where the telephone network will connect to different local hubs.

It sounds like it is the last case that you're seeing on your desktop only, which implies the WiFi networks near you haven't been surveyed with enough confidence for the geolocation to work.